# Is there any way I can define a http filter like what we did in J2EE apps?

Tags: django, http, filter

I am writing an web application using django, I am trying to do user authentication for all http requests, is there any way in django allow me define a http filter like what we do in J2ee, then all http request comes to my filter first then i can do some operations like checking user id, check permisson etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure; use middleware. For more details, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about filters, but i can tell you for sure, is that you can make use of `decorators` in django.

You can create a custom decorator, and attach the custom decorator on top of the view that you want to check for user id, check permission etc.

You can check the following link

https://passingcuriosity.com/2009/writing-view-decorators-for-django/

which is useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot, eventually i solved the problem by using django processor to handle the http request before each view.